# Inner Product on Schwartz Space and $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, inner-products, schwartz-space

For $f, g \in \mathcal{S}$: the inner product is usually given by
$$
\langle f,g \rangle = \int f(x) g(x) dx
$$

whereas for $f, g \in L^2$, the inner product is usually given by
$$
\langle f,g \rangle = \int f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx
$$

Given that the Schwartz space can be regarded as a subspace of $L^2$, how should interpret the difference between their inner products

Comment: Schwartz usually deals with real valued functions, $L^2$ may be complex valued.

Comment: @copper.hat: In my experience, the Schwartz space is often used in connection to Fourier transform and is therefore naturally complex-valued. The other question is maybe: Why do you consider an inner product on the Schwartz space?

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, I should probably have written that for a real valued function there is no difference.